# Using Lagrange error bound for Taylor series defined as the integral of another series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The function *f* is defined by the power series
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4(3)}x + \frac{3}{5(3^2)}x^2 + \cdots + \frac{n+1}{(n+3)3^n}x^n
$$
on its interval of convergence.

Let $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$. If the third-degree Maclaurin series for $g$ is used to estimate $g(-2),$ use the Lagrange error bound to find an upper bound on the error of the approximation.

Of course, $g(x) = \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{1}{4(3)}x^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+3)3^n}x^{n+1}$. **What is the best thought process to determine the maximum of $|g^{(4)}(x)|$ on the interval $[0, -2]$?** I understand that $g'(x) = f(x),$ but having some trouble from there on.

Comment: Check the next term in the sum and estimate by the supremum on $[-2, 0]$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Could you clarify what you mean by "next term in the sum"? Is this for f(x) or g(x)?

Comment: Note that when $x< 0$, this is an alternating series, so the remainder of the sum always has smaller magnitude than the first neglected term.

Comment: By next term, I mean the term in $g$ corresponding to $n=4.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson So we look at the max of $\frac{x^5}{(7*3^4)}$ on [-2, 0]? Could you please explain why this particular term is used? I was thinking that the fourth derivative of g should be used, not just the term in g where n=4?